# SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a SyntaxError in `jquery.validate.min.js` File

How I can solve it?

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
>    /ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js:1

Comment: what is the content of jquery.validate.min.js?

Comment: may be `jquery.validate.min.js` loaded incorrectly .inspect and see the content of this file from the source code (ctrl + u)

Comment: @Sohrab please past here the code, how are you using the .validate function rules? am guessing you put there an HTML tag

Comment: Thank you I solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The error is likely to mean that a `.js` file was fetched but an HTML was returned, probably because of an error 404 or similar. If you'd inspect the file that was fetched in the console (eg: in Chrome or Firefox, <kbd>F12</kbd>, then go to the `network` tab, then click on `jquery.validate.min.js`), you'll see some HTML content instead of the script for `jquery.validate.min.js`. Additionally that'd display the HTML of the error message from the server (404 page not found, 403 forbidden, etc).

You should check your connexion, check that your page has the sufficient authorizations to load content from `ajax.aspnetcdn.com`, and use `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/...` instead of `/ajax.aspnetcdn.com/...` in your script tag.

Comment: @Sohrab glad to hear that :) ! Please note that, as surprising as it may seem, *"thank you comments"* should be avoided here ([here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)) - if an answer is helpful, *accept it* by clicking on the checkmark. When you'll have 15 reputations, you'll also be able to *upvote it*.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` is caused if the `src` of a script tag refers to file which was not found.

So, I recommend you to check the url of the `script`'s `src` for validity.